Git push fails with fatal: unable to access 'https://example.com:github_pat_11AAQ6etc: URL rejected: Port number was not a number between 0 and 65535
...where example.com would be replaced with the URL of my site of course. I'm just working from my home machine. example.com is down but I'm trying to push to github, not my site.
I am also slightly weirded out by the fact that the error messsage includes the GitHub PAT, which exists only in my environment (macOS Sonoma 14.5). Seems like a security problem.

Please show your push command (replacing the token with alphanumeric garbage).

Working in the repo source directory. It's just a simple:
`$ git push`


Then we need to see your remote URL; most probably from git remote get-url origin (replacing the token).

WTF??? You're a genius. When I ran $ git remote get-url origin
it returned https://example.com:github_pat_11AAQ6Tetc, not https://github.com/exampleuserid/examplesite as I expected. I don't remember changing the remote location at all.

git remote set-url origin https://github_pat_11AAQ6Tetc@github.com/exampleuserid/examplesite

There is a github outage right now
https://www.githubstatus.com/
"Update - We are experiencing interruptions in multiple public GitHub services. We suspect the impact is due to a database infrastructure related change that we are working on rolling back."
this is probably your issue.
